# case when pull result from other table

Tags: postgresql, case-when

I have a query that I'm trying to run where I want to pull the addresses of people who work remotely, and only those who work remotely.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.remote = 1 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS remote
FROM addresses A
JOIN member.info B
    ON A.id = b.company_id
```

If I want to build a query that only pulls the address for a 'yes' remote employee and pulls a null value for when A.remote = 0, do I build it into my current CASE WHEN or create a new CASE WHEN? The address is being pulled from the address table and the remote is being pulled from the member.info table and is a boolean.

The resulting table should look like this

```
Remote       Address
Yes          123 St
No           Null
```

I'm using a version of postgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another case expression:

```
CASE WHEN A.remote = 1 THEN A.Address ELSE null END AS Address
```